# Iterate through a pandas dataframe (column by column) and extract all special characters into a list

Tags: python, pandas

Below is the code I've written.

```
my_dict={}

#reading csv into df
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=',', header='infer',encoding='latin1')

#regex for all special characters
regex = re.compile('[^\w\s]|_')

for col in df.columns:
    countx=len(df)
    county=0
    for i in df[col]:
#if no special characters are found
        if(regex.search(str(i)) == None):
            countx=countx-1
        else: 
            county=county+1
    if countx != 0 and county>0:
        my_dict.update({col:'FOUND SPECIAL CHAR'})
    else:
        my_dict.update({col:'NO SPECIAL CHAR'})
```

Currently, I'm able to iterate through the entire dataframe and check if each cell has special characters or not and the results are being written into a dictionary. The output for the above code is as follows.

```
{'col1': 'NO SPECIAL CHAR',
 'col2': 'FOUND SPECIAL CHAR',
 'col3': 'FOUND SPECIAL CHAR',
 'col4': 'NO SPECIAL CHAR',
 'col5': 'FOUND SPECIAL CHAR',
 'col6': 'FOUND SPECIAL CHAR',
 'col7': 'NO SPECIAL CHAR',
 'col8': 'FOUND SPECIAL CHAR',
 'col9': 'FOUND SPECIAL CHAR'}
```

However, I want to make a list of all the special characters. For example, if I found 4 special characters in col1, I would like to display what special characters have been found in that col as well. Please help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: _Please help!_ What specifically is the issue? Please provide a [mcve] and see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Append `special` characters to a list by setting `special = regex.search(str(i)).group()`. Then `.append` to a `listt` object that I have created. and bring that into a dictionary of special characters by column with `my_dict.update({col: listt})`. Finally, reset your `listt` object with `listt = []` in preparation for the next column.

```
#regex for all special characters
import re
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['$1as', '23', '42a', 'f&'],
                  'B':['a', 'b', 'CD', 'a12'],
                  'C':['a', 'b@', 'CD', 'a12']})
regex = re.compile('[^\w\s]|_')
listt = []

for col in df.columns:
    countx=len(df)
    county=0
    for i in df[col]:
#if no special characters are found
        if(regex.search(str(i)) == None):
            countx=countx-1
        else:
            special = regex.search(str(i)).group()
            listt.append(special)
            county=county+1
    if countx != 0 and county>0:
        my_dict.update({col: listt})
        listt = []
    else:
        my_dict.update({col:'NO SPECIAL CHAR'})
my_dict
```

output:

```
{'A': ['$', '&'], 'B': 'NO SPECIAL CHAR', 'C': ['@']}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
example1 =['example1!','_exa!!mple1','e?xam@ple1']
example2 = ['example2','3example2','example2']
example3 = ['exam!!ple3','example3','ex@mple3']

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(example1, example2, example3)), columns =['EXAMPLE 1', 'EXAMPLE 2', 'EXAMPLE 3'])

lista_special_characters = []

def spe_cha(col):
    special = re.findall(r'[^\w\s]|_',col)
    lista_special_characters.extend(special)
    remove_special = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', col)
    return remove_special

df['EXAMPLE 1'] = df.apply(lambda row: spe_cha(row['EXAMPLE 1']), axis=1)

lista_special_characters = list(dict.fromkeys(lista_special_characters))

print(lista_special_characters)

df.head()
```

output:

```
    EXAMPLE 1   EXAMPLE 2   EXAMPLE 3
0   example1    example2    exam!!ple3
1   example1    3example2   example3
2   example1    3example2   3example3


['!', '_', '?', '@'] #unique special characters
```

Comment: Thank you Manuel :)